# How to download image file from Firebase Storage based on a reference of Firebase data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have been struggling for days with this issue.
I'm trying to use Firebase Storage in my web app, the "Upload" part is working fine, and I like it, but the "Download" part is driving me crazy.
Here is my code:

First I have my Firebase (data) reference:

```
var refspaedtServ = new Firebase(FBURLSPA + $routeParams.id);
$scope.spaedServ = $firebaseObject(refspaedtServ);
```

I'm getting my record within an ID.
Second I get my object field call "foto", is the name of the photo that I want to download or show

```
var lafoto = '';
refspaedtServ.on("value", function(rootSnapshot) {
  lafoto = rootSnapshot.val().foto;
  console.log("Inside image ", lafoto)
});
```

So here I get the name of the Photo.
Since this is an asynchronous communication, I was unable to get the value, so I insert a Timeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  console.log("outside ", lafoto);
  $scope.lafoto = lafoto 
}, 1000);
```

So here inside the setTime function, is the "lafoto" value OK.
Then I get the refrence of my Firebase Storage Bucket:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var starsRef = storageRef.child('fotos' + lafoto);
```

Here comes my "Problem", when I tried to download the image, the value of "lafoto" is gone, the url can be construct and there is no binding to my webpage image container   , where I want to show the Photo

```
starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log("la url ", url)  ;
  $scope.url = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
  case 'storage/object_not_found';
});
```

I already made a test, leaving storage reference and starsRef.getDownloadURL inside the setTimeout(function) and it works (part), my url is created correctly, BUT it is no binding to my web page.
If I view the console.log, my url is ok, also if I click on it, show me the photo.

Any advice please?

Best regards,

Victor

Comment: Any advice to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are loosing reference to the `$scope` which may be due to having your async calls outside of the controller (It's hard to say without looking at your entire code).

First instead of `refspaedtServ.on()` followed by a `setTimeout()` you should use `refspaedtServ.once()` which returns a promise and move the rest of your logic inside the promise. Then you should set the promise inside the `$scope` directly. Promises can be used in templates as [this article](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) shows. For example something like this should work:

```
myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope) {
  var refspaedtServ = new Firebase(FBURLSPA + $routeParams.id);
  $scope.spaedServ = $firebaseObject(refspaedtServ);
  $scope.url = refspaedtServ.once("value").then(function(rootSnapshot) {
    var lafoto = rootSnapshot.val().foto;
    console.log("Inside image ", lafoto)
    var starsRef = firebase.storage().ref('fotos' + lafoto);
    return starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      console.log("la url ", url)  ;
      return url;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'storage/object_not_found';
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Now `$scope.url` is assigned the promise which in the end returns the `url` directly (because promises can be piped by returning other promises) and the templates actually support Promises.

Unrelated to your issue: I would advise saving the URL of the image directly inside the Database instead of just the Storage URI. This URL should not change and doing this will save you the additional request every time you want to display the image. For example if you saved this URL in the `fotoUrl` attribute you could just do:

```
myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope) {
  var refspaedtServ = new Firebase(FBURLSPA + $routeParams.id);
  $scope.spaedServ = $firebaseObject(refspaedtServ);
  $scope.url = refspaedtServ.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.val().fotoUrl;
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi Nivco, thank you for your response, unfortunately it does not work for me, it`s the same, I'm still loosing the url scope. But I think it's a good idea to sabe the entire URL on the the database when I'm uploading the image. One question how can I get the "token" value, or get the entire path ?

Comment: Hi Nivco again, I already figured out how to save the path: storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          var laurl = url;
          refspaedtServ.update ({
                      url: laurl,
           }).catch(function(error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case 'storage/object_not_found':
                       console.log("Storage not found")
                      }
              });   Thank you again, for your support

Comment: I think I got it. By looking at the following article: http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/

Comment: Hi Nivco, that is a good article, I will try to use promises in the future, again thank you for your support.